# How to copy this struct with multiple arrays to another temporary struct?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, copy, memcpy

I need to write a function `void findBoursiers(void)` that need to do the following tasks :

1. copy the content of `struct student m_stuTab[STU_NB]` which contain 6 students
   with each

   a) the name of the student (`name[MAX_NAME]`)

   b) the file number (`fileNumber[NB_DIGITS]`)

   c) the score.

I need to copy all this to a temporary struct named `struct student temp_stuTab[STU_NB]` (which is created in `void findBoursiers(void)`).

2. I need take the content of `struct student temp_stuTab[STU_NB]` and take the 3 students with the highest score in order from best to worst. I imagine by comparing them with a for loop.
3. Take those 3 students and put them in an array named `char m_boursiers[3][MAX_NAME]`.

I am required to not change this following code, which is in `main()`

```
struct student {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    char fileNumber[NB_DIGITS];
    int score;
};

struct student m_stuTab[NB_STU];
char m_stuName[NB_STU][MAX_NAME] = {"Mario", "Yoshi", "Luigi", "Peach", "Wario", "Waluigi"};
char m_boursiers[3][MAX_NAME];
```

I know this is feasible with `for` loops, `strcpy` and such but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it. Maybe a process similar to `memcpy` ? I am fairly new to coding so sorry if my question is hard to understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The *"process similar to memcpy"* you refer to is the one you want, I think. In C++ parlance, it's normally used as `std::memcpy`.

Comment: classes and structures that are [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) can be copied with good old `=`. `student` is about as trivial as they come.

Comment: @user4581301 so you are saying that i would only need to write `student temp_stuTab = student m_stuTab` ? because when i try to write this in the function, it gives me an error saying undefined identifier "student". It's my first time using struct so it isn't crystal clear to me

Comment: Just `student temp_stuTab = m_stuTab` to copy *one* structure, or `temp_stuTab[i] = m_stuTab[i]` (in a loop) to copy each element of the array sequentially. But `memcpy` will do it in one fell swoop.

Comment: Hey! Who stole the C++ tag? Dammit! Linking to C++ documentation's kinda off topic now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 student temp_stuTab = student m_stuTab
```

Now I understand the actual question. C and C++ differ here, but that was wrong in any case.

C:

```
 struct student temp_stuTab;
 temp_stuTab = m_stuTab;
```

C++:

```
 student temp_stuTab;
 temp_stuTab = m_stuTab;
```

C++ will accept it the C way, but it's bad style unless you named a struct the same as a variable (which is bad style for a different reason).

Answer (score 0):

To copy an array of structures, use a `for` loop and simple assigments:

```
struct student m_stuTab[NB_STU];
struct student temp_stuTab[NB_STU];

for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_STU; i++) {
    temp_stuTab[i] = m_stuTab[i];
}
```

This is the preferred solution for both C and C++. If you insist on using `memcpy`, you could write:

```
memcpy(temp_stuTab, m_stuTab, sizeof(*temp_stuTab) * NB_STU);
```

But it would not invoke the copy constructors nor the assignment overloaded functions in C++ and the size is easy to miscalculate. Good compilers will generate the same code for both approaches when possible.